# Writing Styled Text to a .docx file

Tags: java, swing, file-io, apache-poi, docx

I'm trying to write an application that will write text to a .docx file. My application uses a JTextPane so the user can write whatever he/she wants, and it also provides many buttons such as bold, font color, font size... ect. What I'm having a problem with is maintaining the style of the text on the JTextPane to when I write to the .docx file. I'm fairly new to Swing and Apache POI so example code and/or a detailed explanation would be helpful.

What I have is this: (pad refers to the JTextPane)

```
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
run.setText(pad.getText());   
document.write(output);
output.close();
```

Answer (score 2):

For my example I assume you'd use a [`HTMLEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) in your [`JTextPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html). I would then parse the [`StyledDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledDocument.html) of the pane and set the textruns accordingly.

Of course this is just a starter, you'd need to parse all the possible styles and convert them yourself in the loop below.

I've to admit, that I've never done something with the HTMLEditorKit and therefore I don't know how to handle the CSS.CssValues properly.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;


public class StyledText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // prepare
        JTextPane pad = new JTextPane();
        pad.setContentType("text/html");
        HTMLEditorKit kit = (HTMLEditorKit)pad.getEditorKit();
        HTMLDocument htmldoc = (HTMLDocument)kit.createDefaultDocument();
        kit.insertHTML(htmldoc, htmldoc.getLength(), "<p>paragraph <b>1</b></p>", 0, 0, null);
        kit.insertHTML(htmldoc, htmldoc.getLength(), "<p>paragraph <span style=\"color:red\">2</span></p>", 0, 0, null);
        pad.setDocument(htmldoc);

        // convert
        StyledDocument doc = pad.getStyledDocument();
        XWPFDocument docX = new XWPFDocument();

        int lastPos=-1; 
        while (lastPos < doc.getLength()) {
            Element line = doc.getParagraphElement(lastPos+1);
            lastPos = line.getEndOffset();
            XWPFParagraph paragraph = docX.createParagraph();
            for (int elIdx=0; elIdx < line.getElementCount(); elIdx++) {
                final Element frag = line.getElement(elIdx);

                XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();
                String subtext = doc.getText(frag.getStartOffset(), frag.getEndOffset()-frag.getStartOffset());
                run.setText(subtext);

                final AttributeSet as = frag.getAttributes();
                final Enumeration<?> ae = as.getAttributeNames();

                while (ae.hasMoreElements()) {
                    final Object attrib = ae.nextElement();

                    if (CSS.Attribute.COLOR.equals(attrib)) {
                        // I don't know how to really work with the CSS-swing class ...
                        Field f = as.getAttribute(attrib).getClass().getDeclaredField("c");
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        Color c = (Color)f.get(as.getAttribute(attrib));
                        run.setColor(String.format("%1$02X%2$02X%3$02X", c.getRed(),c.getGreen(),c.getBlue()));
                    } else if (CSS.Attribute.FONT_WEIGHT.equals(attrib)) {
                        if ("bold".equals(as.getAttribute(attrib).toString())) {
                            run.setBold(true);
                        }
                    }
                }               
            }
        }

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.docx"); 
        docX.write(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright it looks good except that this code doesn't write anything to the file. I've gone through it and I couldn't find a mistake (although Im new at this so I easily could have missed it). Could you look the code over and see what the problem is? If it would help I could send you all of my code for my application but it is at 630 lines already. Thanks for the help

Comment: I've tested the result of the stand-alone example above with Libre Office and it showed the two lines ... so you mean, it doesn't show something in combination with your JTextPane code?! If you don't want to paste your code here, just copy it to pastebin.com and add a link to it ... but I can't reply before 04.08.13 anyways ...

Comment: I found out that in my buttons I'm using to change the style of the text I'm using a StyledEditorKit. for example i have a line of code in a JMenu that says: new StyledEditorKit.ForegroundAction("Black", Color.BLACK); which changes the color to the text to black when you begin to start typing again. I remember shying away from an HTMLEditorKit because I dont know HTML.

Comment: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML can convert XHTML to docx content, but it requires docx4j and its dependencies.

Comment: @user2608775: For the convert part of the example, you'll have to find out anyway, which attributes are used in your [`StyledEditorKit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyledEditorKit.html) (i.e. a RTF/HTMLEditorKit). So please don't shy away from using a debugger and customize the if-else-part of the loop (... as mentioned in the answer)