# Insert HTML content in PPT using apache poi java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to insert few html content programmatically to ppt file generated using apache poi.

Does pptx poi framework supports inserting html content to the ppt slides?

Comment: its possible look at http://poi.apache.org/slideshow/xslf-cookbook.html#NewPresentation

Comment: in the example, it shows to add text in the PPT, that works, but want to add html content, text with html tags. should display as html formatted content

Comment: html text is a text so you should be able to write tags as text

Comment: That didnt work. That display as tags itself. its not getting formatted.

Comment: what you mean by formatting. you can always format a text whatever ways you want

Comment: I want to set HTML content to display in the ppt, for example <b>bold</b> should display as **bold** like that

Comment: This is not going to happen. That is not formatting. that is rendering of html which will not happen in ppt. The browser understands html tags. ppt is not a browser.

Comment: why would you write in ppt if you want to render it as html page?

Comment: I did [something similar for docx](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17800017/writing-styled-text-to-a-docx-file/17823048#17823048) ... maybe I try to write something like this for H/XSLF too ...

Comment: what you did looks really nice... if you can manage to do the same for pptx it will be great

Comment: Okay let's say I want to export a graphic chart or even the content of a pbi report in an iframe from HTML to PowerPoint  . Ideally, in order to get the expected result, the process should be able to first identify the content of the HTML element id, then if it's NOT limited to text,....being able to take a snapshot of the content then convert it as an image which the PowerPoint conversion tool may be able to recognize. In most Powerpoint cases, graphics are mainly static images... and that's a lot of coding...